# SNMP Agent for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, snmp, net-snmp

I have to handle a scenario in OpenNMS where I need to health-monitor the PostgreSQL DB using SNMP agent. I would really appreciate if someone give me an idea if there is such agent already implemented.

Thanks,

Suri.

Answer (score 1):

First result with google [pgsnmpd](http://pgsnmpd.projects.postgresql.org/) when you search for postgresql snmp

Answer (score 1):

yes I have using [SNMP](http://www.oidview.com/mibbrowser.html) from Oidview, it should help.